# Select a distinct column with it's relative id

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I feel like this has been asked before so I apologize for that but I haven't been able to find an answer yet(maybe I'm searching in the wrong place?)

What I want to do: I have 2 columns in my table: `id` and `value`. I am trying to retrieve the value and id from the table so I can populate a drop down list for the user. (simple enough)

Problem: my `value` column has sometimes repeating data, so I want to do a `distinct(value)` so that I only get distinct values instead of all the duplicates, BUT I also want to get the id for each distinct value.

```
ex: What I have
id    |    value
---        -----
1          Example1
2          Example1
3          Example2
4          Example3
5          Example4
6          Example4

result:
id    |    value
---        -----
1          Example1
3          Example2
4          Example3
5          Example4
```

any ideas on how to approach this?

I realized this doesn't work:

```
SELECT distinct(value), id FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
 select * from table1
 where id in (select min(id) from table1 group by `value`)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/116431/5)

Comment: thank you kind sir. Will accept when the timer allows me